# What are the differences between regular and limited version of Planescape - Adventures in the Multiverse set?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, books

The set of books for Planescape - Adventures in the Multiverse will start shipping 20.10.2023, in a bit less than a month from when this question is written.

Limited edition is much more expensive, and reservations are going fast. Is there a difference, besides "limited" status and alternative cover? Is there anything that would make a difference, game-wise? Especially additional content etc that people who will not get limited edition will miss?

Answer (score 8):

### Content for the two versions is the same

[*Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse*](https://dndstore.wizards.com/us/en/product/820944/planescape-adventures-in-the-multiverse-digital-plus-physical-bundle) will be available with the normal and an alternate cover. There is no statement that the content of the alternate cover versions differs in any way, and indeed it looks exactly the same, except for the exterior. This was also the case for all prior products that had alternate covers. Without any announcement from them changing this practice, and with no additional items visible, it is extremely improbable this would be different:

[image] [image]

There is a set of painted miniatures that are sold in a [limited edition boxed set](https://www.jedishop.eu/d-d-icons-of-the-realms-planescape-prepainted-miniature-adventures-in-the-multiverse-limited-edition-boxed-set-902050511/), but that is an entirely separate purchase from the boxed set.

If what makes you wonder is the high price, Wizards made an [announcement on increasing prices](https://gizmodo.com.au/2023/05/dungeons-dragons-books-will-cost-even-more-now/). They have track record and experience in charging extra for functionally identical content by making it look different, and limiting the number available. They do it with *Magic: the Gathering* cards, too. Some people are happy to pay a significant premium to get a special version they can show off or collect.

Comment: I imagine Molot wasn’t able to find any statement about the content either, hence the question. It isn’t clear to me that you’ve provided anything beyond what they already knew, so I’ve downvoted for now. This answer reads like a guess in the absence of helpful information.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov exactly, I couldn't find authors or publishers state one way or another. I was guessing its only the cover,  but I believe both me personally and community as a whole coud use a solid knowledge on that matter. When I'll be able to compare physical sets, it'll be too late for most to buy alt cover.

Comment: @Molot Do you have a link to the offer? Because I have been entirely unable to find anything separate other than the alt cover version. And Wizards have bern doing alt covers for a long time, it's just a way to cash in on the players that are willing to a special version like with foil magic cards, which also are functionally identical. Nothing anywhere indicates this would be any different from what has been their practice for years.

Comment: Honestly, the fact that they're not advertising differences in content between these two produces is a pretty big signifier that there is no difference. If there _was_ extra content in the limited edition, they would definitely want to advertise it to boost sales.

Comment: Your link titled "Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse" is to the Spelljammer set...

Comment: @ShadowRanger Huh? Which one - the one at the very start gies to "PSAITM Digital & Physical Bundle" for me. Is that the one you mean? The other one goes to an Icons miniature box, but it also says PSAITM for me

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin: indigochild fixed it for you.

Comment: Ah, missed that. @indigochild, Thank you!

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin https://przyczolek.pl/dnd-planescape-limited for example. And this is the first time I see something I want available in my country with this choice. If there's a canonical question about general publishing customs etc, I'm ok with closing mine as a duplicate. I also can't be sure what was lost in the translation. Google is contextual these days, so what you know and can google up is different from what I know and can google up.

Comment: @Molot, thanks for the link. My Polish is shaky (erm, nonexistent, basically), but the list of items on that page looks to me like the list on the wizards announcement for the non-alt cover one: the three books, poster map, and master screen. Nothin else. I have some books with alt covers, and they look to have exctly the same content, to the point that on the credit page, the cover and alt cover are both listed with artist credit. I've not been able to dig up the original alt cover announcemnt, which maybe could contain a clear statement on content being the same yet, thoug.

Comment: The oldest publicationd with an alt cover are Volos and XGE. The term alt-cover also suggests that it is really just the cover that differs. With XGE being rules content, it would be very weird if there was a "premium" version with extra, different rules, for example.

Comment: Hasbro is doing an excellent job killing off Wizards. I hope that by the time they are done, MCDM will have finished their game system. Now I just need to find a good replacement for MTG...